# Why is Swift counting this Grapheme Cluster as two characters instead of one?

Tags: swift, unicode, emoji, grapheme

Generally Swift is *really* smart about counting grapheme clusters as a single character. If I want to make a Lebanese flag, for example, I can combine the two Unicode characters

- U+1F1F1 REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER L
- U+1F1E7 REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER B

and as expected this is one character in Swift:

```
let s = "\u{1f1f1}\u{1f1e7}"
assert(s.characters.count == 1)
assert(s.utf16.count == 4)
assert(s.utf8.count == 8)
```

However, let's say I want to make a Bicyclist emoji of Fitzpatrick Type-5. If I combine

- U+1F6B4 BICYCLIST
- U+1F3FE EMOJI MODIFIER FITZPATRICK TYPE-5

Swift counts this combination as *two* characters!

```
let s = "\u{1f6b4}\u{1f3fe}"
assert(s.characters.count == 2)   // <----- WHY?
assert(s.utf16.count == 4)
assert(s.utf8.count == 8)
```

Why is this two characters instead of one?

To show why I would expect it be 1, note that this cluster is actually interpreted as a valid emoji:

[image]

Comment: This looks like a bug report. Why not send it to the Swift team?

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr51/ is a bit vague: "Whenever one of these characters immediately follows certain characters (such as WOMAN), then a font should show the sequence as a single glyph ..."

Comment: There is discussion of this point at https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-375 . Unfortunately, that does not throw much light on the situation.

Comment: Wow, I had not seen that Swift bug report! I probably should have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of the answer is given in the [bug report](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-375?focusedCommentId=11324&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-11324) mentioned in emrys57's comment. When splitting a Unicode string into "characters", Swift apparently uses the Grapheme Cluster Boundaries defined in [UAX #29 Unicode Text Segmentation](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Grapheme_Cluster_Boundaries). There's a [rule not to break between regional indicator symbols](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr29/#GB12), but there is no such rule for Emoji modifiers. So, according to UAX #29, the string `"\u{1f6b4}\u{1f3fe}"` contains two grapheme clusters. See [this message](http://unicode.org/mail-arch/unicode-ml/y2015-m06/0190.html) from Ken Whistler on the Unicode mailing list for an explanation:

> This results from the fact that the fallback behavior for the modifiers is
>   simply as independent pictographic blorts, i.e. the color swatch images. [...] You need additional, specific
>   knowledge about these sequences -- it doesn't just fall out from a
>   *default* implementation of UAX #29 rules for grapheme clusters.